# Using regex to find-and-replace an arbitrary number of elements per match

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to recognize bold parenthesized text in a markup language, eg.:

```
[B] blah blah (foo) blah [/B]
```

and use regex to surround it with another tag, like so:

```
[B] blah blah [C](foo)[/C] blah [/B]
```

Here's my attempt at this using Python:

```
outtext = re.sub(r'(\[B\].*?)(\(.*?\))(.*?\[/B\])', r'\1[C]\2[/C]\3', intext)
```

The problem is, it doesn't work if there are multiple parenthesized strings within the block:

```
Input: [B] (foo) (bar) [/B]
Expected: [B] [C](foo)[/C] [C](bar)[/C] [/B]
Actual: [B] [C](foo)[/C] (bar) [/B]
```

I know the reason why this is happening, but I don't know how to fix it. Is it possible to change my regex so that it's able to find-and-replace an arbitrary number of parenthesized strings within each block, as opposed to just one?

Comment: Basic idea to handle this would be to have two regex, first to select the values inside `B` tag, then second to capture values inside `()` and replace, i don't think you can do it with a single regex

Comment: If the text between the parentheses is freeform and may contain other escaped parenthesis.. the other answers aren't going to have much application beyond simple cases. If what I said is true, you might want to take a look at my =) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is typically resolved by replacing matches only inside other matches. You need to run a `re.sub` with a regex that will match all `B` tagged substrings, and replace multiple occurrences of strings between parentheses only inside those matches using a callable in `re.sub` as a replacement argument.

Here is the solution:

```
import re
text = "[B] blah blah (foo) blah [/B]\n[B] (foo) (bar) [/B]"
print(re.sub(r'(?s)\[B].*?\[/B]', lambda x: re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', r'[C]\g<0>[/C]', x.group()), text))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/f3JZwd).

**NOTE**: If you have longer texts, unroll the lazy dot pattern and use

```
r'\[B][^[]*(?:\[(?!/?B])[^[]*)*\[/B]'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yv2HeX/1).

Output:

```
[B] blah blah [C](foo)[/C] blah [/B]
[B] [C](foo)[/C] [C](bar)[/C] [/B]
```

The `(?s)\[B].*?\[/B]` pattern matches `[B]`, then 0+ chars as few as possible up to the leftmost `[/B]` (note `(?s)` allows the `.` to match any char including line break chars). Then, once a match is found, it is passed to the callable, and the `\([^()]*\)` regex is run on that match. `\([^()]*\)` matches any substring between the closest parentheses, i.e. `(`, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`. The `\g<0>` in the replacement pattern is a replacement backreference to the whole match.

Answer (score 2):

First I thought regex alone is not capable of solving the problem. JvdV prooved this wrong, well done. Honestly, I do not understand this regex anymore.

I solved it with some easier regex and a bit of python

```
import re

intext = '[B] (foo) (bar) [/B] (not) [B] (this again) [/B]'

boldParts = re.findall(r'\[B\].*?\[/B\]', intext)
outtext = intext
for part in boldParts:
    replacement = re.sub(r'(\(.*?\))', r'[C]\1[/C]', part)
    outtext = outtext.replace(part, replacement)

print(outtext)
```

First I look for only the bold parts in the intext, then it's easy to replace the thing in parentheses. And replace it in the outtext again.

Admittedly not the shortest or most elegant way of doing it, but maybe a little more readable.

Comment: would you suggest I explain the expression in more detail? I would but need to have some confirmation first that it is correct =). Kudos to your answer +

Comment: I was curious about how your regex worked. And I looked it up in the link you provided.
That helped a little. Then I found https://www.debuggex.com/r/mRS0i3CnQvNjH0T7
to visualize it. Then it made click and i got it.
For me just this visualization was key.
Didn't know about (?! ) reverse lookup only simple [^ ]. So thanks, learned something today. :)

Comment: I would have added this link as a comment on your answer. but I am not yet allowed to leave a comment :((

Comment: Added it for you =). Btw, added the `\B` to prevent matches on `test(test)test`

Comment: Thanks, I feel honored =)

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. this took me some time.. I'm not sure of the specifics of the markup syntax, but I'll make some assumptions: the text inside parenthesis can be any character except parenthesis unless they are escaped. The escape character is a backslash. With that said.. here's what I came up with.

```
>>> expr = r"""
...    \(                            # Match left paren.
...       (
...         (?:      [^ \( \) \\] |  # Match any char not a paren or escape, OR
...              \\  [  \( \) \\] |  # Match an escaped paren or escape, OR
...              \s                  # whitespace.
...          )*
...        )
...    \)                            # Match right paren. """
...
>>> re.sub(expr, r"[C](\1)[/C]",  "[B] (foo) (bar) [/B]", flags=re.VERBOSE)
'[B] [C](foo)[/C] [C](bar)[/C] [/B]'
```

This will also work with target strings that have escaped parenthesis in them. The abbreviated form of the above is this...

```
re.sub(r"\(((?:[^\(\)\\]|\\[\(\)\\]|\s)*)\)", 
       r"[C](\1)[/C]",  "[B] (foo) (bar) [/B]")
```

With the whitespace and comments taken out...

Comment: I belive the reason that [^\(\)\\] didn't match whitespace in the expression is a side effect of using re.VERBOSE expression syntax. So that's why the '\s' alt is in the expression.

Comment: Also, note that this expression could be modified easily if the escapes for parenthesis were something like '((' and '))'. I think people can appreciate how much more manageable expressions are from this using the re.VERBOSE flag =)